# End of Personal Fast?

Tags: zemanim, fast-days, sunset-shekia

When does one end their personal fast? At sunset? or do they wait until 3 stars come out like at the end of Shabbos?

Comment: This wasn't limited to personal fasts when the answer was posted, and when I saw your question I thought you were asking about the communal fasts (like 17 Tamuz).  The answer still answers your question, but you might want to let the author know about your change to the question.

Comment: According to the Tanya, you could even end your fast after halachic midday. Doing this twice adds up to one fast. This is considered acceptable fasting practice (by the Tanya) but ideally not for all personal fasts, only some

Answer (score 1):

[Halachipedia](http://halachipedia.com/index.php?title=Fast_Days) says:

> When does the fast start?
>
> 1. Communal fasts which do not start at night only begin at Alos HaShachar. [32]
>
> [32] S”A 564:1
>
> 2. When does the Fast end?
>      Any fast which one didn’t complete until Tzeis HaKochovim is considered as though one didn't fast. [37]
>
> [37] S”A 562:1

Tzeis HaKochovim is when the stars come out. For the time when Shabbos goes out, we add an extra time called [Tosephes Shabbos](http://www.halacha2go.com/blog/tx00345/)  - a minimum of 4 minutes.

Comment: So if you end the fast at sunset the fast is not complete?

Comment: @eagle The opinion presented here is a rather stringent one. Most Rishonim think sunset is sufficient for most fasts (except 9Av and YK)

Comment: related http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/44204/why-dont-rabbinic-fasts-end-by-ben-hashmashot?rq=1 where @Double AA says, "So either way we are going to wait until pretty close to nightfall. (Note that "nightfall" here would mean when average size stars come out, not small stars like we are stringent for regarding biblical issues like Shabbat....."

Comment: But like if you mess up the time because of a mistake,The fast has no meaning?Hashem won't care about it?

Comment: @AvrohomYitzchok That's all if you are trying to get to nightfall (as the OP there asked about why not say Safek Lekula by Bein HaShemashot and declare it night at sunset). But accd to the majority opinion in Rishonim sunset itself is fine. The Arukh haShulchan says straight out that one shouldn't reprimand someone who eats after sunset "ולפי זה נראה לעניות דעתי דהסומך על רבותינו אלה להתענות רק עד בין השמשות – אין מזניחין אותו"

Comment: @DoubleAA Accepted. Can't argue with the Arukh haShulchan.

Comment: I'm not sure this is always true for example תענית בכורות does not end at tzeis b/c one is not permitted to enter into the yontiff while fasting. Another example are a chosson and kallah don't have to wait until tzeis but only until after the chuppah to end their fast (obviously also only if it is their custom to fast). Lastly, while I can't find any examples at the moment I recall in the past where there have been fast days that ended slightly before tzeis and so I'm not sure that waiting until exactly tzeis is always the case for every single fast day.

Comment: Being that the question is about a personal fast wouldn't the extent of the personal fast be determined by the persona who undertakes such a fast?